# clion debugger stops working after one step

Tags: c++, c, debugging, clion

I have a weird problem with the CLion debugger.

When I put a breakpoint or two and then hit the debug button, the debugger would initialize and stop at the first breakpoint. But then when I hit any of the step buttons in the console (Step Over, Step Into), it executes the line and then it won't allow me to step any more. The debugging process is still on, but I can't in fact do anything.

It's worth mentioning that this problem occurs only with projects that I create in CLion in my computer. When a friend creates a new CLion project and shares it with me, the CLion debugger works just fine when I use it with this project **in the same computer** (mine).

Any clue would be appreciated!

Comment: sounds like something is not installed correctly on your computer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and it turned out single-stepping worked only for the first few lines of code - until I called gethostname() followed by WSACleanup(). When one of them was commented out, the single stepping worked fine (F7/F8).

This is on a Windows 10 machine, and the functions are part of Microsoft's WinSock implementation.